# QGIS: Export ShapeFile-Layer with image coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, image, pixel

I am completely new to QGIS and I am trying to solve this issue:

I have 3 layers: OpenStreetMap, an image and my shapefile layer with polygons.
All polygons are within the image.
Is it somehow possible to export the polygons as GeoJSON, but use the image coordinates instead of a CRS?
So (0,0) would be one of the corners and the polygon points would have pixel coordinates.

Comment: By definition, GeoJSON is in WGS84 decimal degrees.

Comment: @Vince ah okay, I didnt know about that. Than another format would be more suitable. Is this somehow possible with something else? Maybe just a JSON?